# Presenting view use scaling animation constraints error [Swift]

Tags: swift4

in my swift app I’ve some issues about view constraints.
I present this view(.xib file) by using scale method to get scale from center animation.

```
view.addSubview(xibView)
UIView.animate(duration: 0.5) {
    xibView.transform = scaleBy(x: 0.01, y: 0.01)
}, completion: { _ in
    xibView.transform = .identity
})
```

But I lose all constraints in this way and this happen only with iPad.
What’s the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you add or remove a view to another view you loose any previous constraints you had.
You need to set the constraints after adding `xibView` to `view`.